# UrlFetchApp.fetch( ) url with |

Tags: url, encoding, scripting, google-apps-script, fetch

I have a url I want to get using google scripts' UrlFetchApp.fetch( ) command. Unfortunately this url has a | (gets partially encoded into %7c) in it and every time i try to fetch it I get an error saying 'invalid argument'. Any idea how to get around this issue and successfully fetch the url?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work if the url passed to `UrlFetchApp.fetch` is already encoded.

Let's say you want to fetch www.google.com/aaa|bbb (which doesn't really exist). The following script fails with "invalid argument":

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("www.google.com/aaa|bbb");
```

But this one correctly returns a 404 as the request is valid but the page is not found:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("www.google.com/aaa%7Cbbb");
```

If that doesn't help, it would help if you could paste your url.

Comment: My url is: https://graph.facebook.com/138326442889677/insights?access_token=authoken  'authtoken' being replaced by my actual authtoken. It was the authtoken that had the | in it. Thanks for the response by the way- I've been tearing my hair out over this and I really need the help.

Comment: when i encode the token facebook doesn't recognize the token and gives me an authorization error